# selenium webdriver logging levels - disable driver debug logs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Since version 2.37 or so, webdriver-java has started logging extensively, it fills up the logs. I have been trying to investigate how to turn down the logging, but so far with no luck. Do anybody know how to set this?

Output from current log:

```
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< connection: close
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< content-length: 93
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< server: httpd.js
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.headers:<< date: Mon, 06 Jan 2014 15:23:44 GMT
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.wire:<< "{"name":"addCookie","sessionId":"81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735","status":0,"value":""}"
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection:Connection 0.0.0.0:23053<->127.0.0.1:7055 shut down
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager:Released connection is not reusable.
DEBUG 01-06 17:23:44 Forwarding addCookie on session 81e0107f-bb03-494e-b23a-d878402eb735 to remote--org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute:Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055][null]
```

thousands of rows like this.

EDIT:
I have found the LoggingPreferences class, but it doesn't change anything:

```
LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.WARNING);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.WARNING);
loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.WARNING);

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);
```

Comment: That doesn't happen to me and I always use the latest webdriver.. currently 2.39.

Comment: I have the same problem but with `Marionette DEBUG [2147483649] Received DOM event`

Answer (score 0):

It was actually Browsermob proxy filling the logs. 
I swiched back to **net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-proxy:2.0-beta-8**, and everythin is back to normal.